# Delete a Band by c# code in Stimulsoft Reports

Tags: asp.net, stimulsoft

I have a report by Stimulsoft Reports in ASP.Net WebForms.

It has a PageHeaderBand and a DataBand.
I want to delete the PageHeaderBand of report in runtime (when user clicks on a custom button)

please help me.

Comment: @MASh please don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: I didn't use inline code !

Comment: No, an editor did, and shouldn't have. I rolled the edit back for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :

```
StiReport report = ...;
StiComponent component = report.GetComponentByName("<CustomName>");
report.GetComponents().remove(component);
```